# Problems installing latest version of MySQL

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, mysql

I'm trying to install the latest version of MySQL (5.5.13 64-bit) on Windows 7 64-bit, but when it starts to configure the security settings, it shows this error:

[image]

What can I do? Note: the port is configured on 3307.

Comment: Have you actually checked out the firewall issue mentioned in the error message? If so, let us know.

Comment: Yes, I have even disabled the firewall, and the windows 7 built-in firewall is disabled too.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is because of the Windows 7 firewall. You can either turn off the firewall or add a rule that would allow MySql through the firewall.

[This page](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/) explains how to open a port in your firewall.

Good-luck!

Comment: The windows 7 firewall is disabled, so I think that's not the problem, because I can install mysql version 5.1 without problems.